# How to add button to position in checkout section by inheriting module available in odoo 12?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-12

I did but the button is not displayed, below is my code.

**custom_buttom_payment.js:**

```js
odoo.define('pos_custom_button_payment.custom_button_payment', function (require) {
"use strict";

var screen = require('point_of_sale.screens');

screen.PaymentScreenWidget.include({
    renderElement: function() {
        var self = this;
        this._super();
        this.$('.js_clear_orderline').click(function(){

        });
    },
});
});
```

**button_custom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="PaymentScreenWidget">
        <t t-jquery="div[class*='js_set_customer']" t-operation="after">
            <div class='left_button js_clear_orderline'>
                <div class="button-icon">
                    <img src="/pos_custom_button_payment/static/src/icons/icon.png" class="pos_logo"/> 
                </div>
                <div class='button-name'>
                    HELLO
                </div>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

**view.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="pos_custom_button" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/pos_custom_button_payment/static/src/js/custom_button_payment.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Hope everyone can help me, I've tried many ways but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the template file under the `qweb` entry in the manifest file

***Example:***

```py
'qweb': ['static/src/xml/button_custom.xml'],
```